# Style last and second last <li> tags using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

Is there any way to style last and second `<li>` tags using CSS. I tried using `ul li:nth-child(6)` and gave a `padding-top:10px;` to it, but the padding top is changing of all menu.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 5</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 6</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 7</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any other way to solve this or am I missing something in my CSS? Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Worth noting that the nth-child selector won't work in IE8 and lower IE browsers. For full support you could use a jQuery based solution (other javascript libraries are available :p)

Comment: Your code seems to be working find in Firefox for me. What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/YZRDY/

Comment: yea its working fine in chrome also

Answer (score 5):

As other similar suggestions, this solution does not work on some older browsers:

```
ul li:last-child, ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

This way, the style sheet does not depend on the specific number of items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li :nth-child(6)
     {
       padding-top:10px;
     }
ul li:last-child
    {
      padding-top:10px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 5</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Menu 6</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Menu 7</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

and in the css file

```
.last
        {
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As said above, the code DOES work:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 5</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 6</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 7</span></a></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul li:nth-child(6)
{
    padding-top:10px;
}​
```

Probably your browser doesn't have compatible CSS3 selectors (no chance if you're using IE).
Here is a simple browser support list: [nth-child support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
 ul li:nth-child(6), ul li:nth-child(7) {
    padding-top:10px;
}
```